# Tableau aggregation into bins of value ranges

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I am trying to visualize my data based on an aggregation of their corresponding values. My input data looks like this:

```
| id | value |
  34    0.5 
  35    0.6 
  37    0.7  
  38    1.1  
  39    1.2  
  40    2.5
```

The goal would be to transform it into this table:

```
| value range | sum(id) |
    0-0.9          3
    1-1.9          2
    2-2.9          1
```

Ideally the visualization would be a bar chart, where I can adjust the range width interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Tableau click the value and then create-> bins